# Was any other religion as exact in terms of genealogy as Judaism?

Tags: religion, judaism, genealogy

Old Testament has extensive genealogies dating from Adam (untraceable) to Jesus, (somewhat traceable). My question is, was any other religion (Greek Paganism, Sumerian Religion, Babylonian Religion, Assyrian Religion, Egyptian Paganism etc) as exact as Judaism?

Comment: The OLD testament does not have a genealogy up to Jesus. Maybe you are counting the New Testament as well? Also, the genealogies in the bible does not need to be considered exact, some consider that Jewish genealogies could, by custom or lack of space, skip generations and keep only the most important persons.  Otherwise, we would be obliged to accept a few thousand years as the age of humanity since Adam.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: I haven't studied the topic in years, but I seem to recall that Oriental religions place a high value on ancestor lineage.  I also believe there are many pre-modern poetic vehicles that emphasize ancestral lines.  IIRC the House of Windsor can trace their lineage to Odin - (The presence of Odin suggests that it was not influenced by Judaism).

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace In fact they have a document that shows their ancestry back to Adam & Eve (and so directly to God), via Odin, Jesus, King David and many others.  It turns out that the former Olympic rower Mathew Pincent and the actor Danny Dyer also have gateway ancestors that link them to that genealogy, so if you can find their episodes of *Who do you think you are?* you can see the document.

Comment: Probably not the spirit of the question, but Confucianism puts great stock in family history and [his descendants are traced down to this day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_tree_of_Confucius_in_the_main_line_of_descent)

Answer (score 9):

The Sumerians did in fact have a very similar work, the [King List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumerian_King_List). It predates [the "begats" of Genesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genealogies_of_Genesis) by a considerable margin. Like about a millineum and a half.

Most likely it was done for roughly the same reason too: as a work of propaganda to back up certain peoples' claim to rightful long-time rulership of their region.

The [genealogies tying Jesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genealogy_of_Jesus) back to that previous Jewish genealogy were done even later than that (somewhere around another half millennium, 70-80AD). The presumed motivation there was to retrospectively burnish his "Messiah" credentials, as some sources in the Hebrew scriptures state a Jewish Messiah has to be of the line of King David. To a lot of Jews at the time, his later followers claims that he was that Messiah would not be credible without that.

---

As an aside to literalists, there are actually **two** [genealogies for Jesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genealogy_of_Jesus), one in Matthew and one in Luke. They are both identical up to David (which makes sense as they could copy that bit from the existing Hebrew Scriptures), but are completely different thereafter. For those of us not burdened with supporting any prexisting dogmas, this is a pretty clear indication both were created separately, not using the same sources, if in fact either was created using any source whatsoever.